# Выполнение проверки после авторизации Ларавел

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.7

как в контроллере LoginController после успешной авторизации сделать такую вот проверку?

```
if (Auth::user()->holiday == 1) User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['holiday' => 0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth::user()->holiday === 1 ? Auth::user()->update(['holiday' => 0]) : false;
```

Comment: а как прописать функцию в LoginController  в которой это проверять и чтобы эта функция сработала?

Comment: так и прописать.
скопировать мою строчку и вставить в логинконтроллер.

если авторизация была успешной, то Auth::user() возвращает модель юзера, где через стрелку вы получаете его свойства.
если Auth::user()->holiday === 1 , то отработает update модели:
Auth::user()->update(['holiday' => 0])

если же Auth::user()->holiday не равен 1 , то ничего не произойдет.